# Elasticsearch 1st query is slow even if I use "loading:eager"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using this kind of mapping (well, it's a shortener version in order to make the question easier) on a children-parent relationship where `item` is the `parent` and `user_items` is the `children`.

```
    curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex?pretty=true' -d '{
      "mappings": {
        "items": {
           "dynamic": "strict",
           "properties" : {
                "title" : { "type": "string" },
                "body" : { "type": "string" },
    }},
        "user_items": {
          "dynamic": "strict",
          "_parent": {"type": "items" },
          "properties" : {
                "user_id" : { "type": "integer" },
                "source_id" : { "type": "integer" },
    }}}}'
```

And the type of query I usually make:

```
    curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/items/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
        "query": {
          "bool": {
             "must": [
                {
                   "query_string": {
                      "fields": ["title", "body"],
                      "query": "mercado"
                   }
                },
                {
                   "has_child": {
                      "type": "user_items",
                      "query": {
                         "term": {
                            "user_id": 655
        }}}}]}}}'
```

On this query it has to search on the fields `title` and `body` the string `mercado` on a given `user_id`, in this case `655`.

The first of these query is veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery slow, it can take up to 15 seconds. The following ones are quite fast (<0.5 sec)

I read that the reason of being so slow the first query is that it  gets cacheed and then the rest queries are fast because it works with  the cached content.

I read I can use `"loading" : "eager"` to boost the first query. So I created a new mapping on a new index with the name `myindex_new`

```
    {
      "mappings": {
        "items": {
           "dynamic": "strict",
           "properties" : {
                "title" : { "type": "string" ,
                            "fielddata": {
                                "loading" : "eager"}},
                "body" : { "type": "string",
                            "fielddata": {
                                "loading" : "eager"}},
    }},
        "user_items": {
          "dynamic": "strict",
          "_parent": {"type": "items" },
          "properties" : {
                "user_id" : { "type": "integer" },
                "source_id" : { "type": "integer" },
    }}}}'
```

... and reindexed everything as follows:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex' -d '{
    "source" : {
        "index" : "myindex"
    },
    "dest" : {
        "index" : "myindex_new"
    }
}'
```

The thing is that I'm not getting any better results. The first query is still slow if I query the new index with the `eager` on it. I also tried by adding the `eager` on the child fields but its still slow.

Do I've to make anything different? I'm doing something wrong on the re-index or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Elasticsearch 2.3

Comment: Fielddata is used for sorting and aggregating on those specific fields. It won't help with your specific query because you don't use those fields for sorting or inside aggregations. I'd try a different type of eager loading and on the child not the fields of the parent: `"loading": "eager_global_ordinals"`. More complete example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-performance.html#_global_ordinals_and_latency). Also, don't forget that the filter cache plays a role as well :-).

Comment: According to the docs `"loading" : "eager"` preload this field’s contents into memory, so it can be used to speed up the queries. So I'm a bit confused after your reply (as you state is used for sorting and aggregations) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html#eager-fielddata So you mean that I should try only add the `eager_global_ordinals` on the children and leave the parent as it is?

Comment: Add `eager_global_ordinals` as depicted in the link I provided and remove the one you added.

Comment: The fields on the `_parent` field is a integer (`user_id` on the example), if I put `eager_globals_ordinals` there it will have no impact as the docs states `Ordinals are only built and used for strings. Numerical data (integers, geopoints, dates, etc) doesn’t need an ordinal mapping, since the value itself acts as an intrinsic ordinal mapping.` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html#eager-global-ordinals (the `Note` part). It's a bit confusing.

Comment: I gave you a different documentation link to use: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-performance.html#_global_ordinals_and_latency

Comment: Yes, I know, but both of them are talking about the same thing `eager_global_ordinals`

Comment: `Parent-child uses global ordinals to speed up joins.` Global ordinals have two purposes: the one you referenced in your link and the one I referenced in my link. I am referring to the type of global ordinals used for the join (as in inner-join) between a parent and its children. How do you think ES does the `has_child` part? It's using in-memory joins between parents and children. For these joins the global ordinals are used. They need to be built and pre-loaded. My suggestion is to do this preloading following the instructions in that link.

Comment: As I already mentioned, this is not the only thing reflecting the increase response time of the first query. You also have query caching which is not pre-loaded. The queries are cached automatically based on a series of optimizations depending on each query type.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try adding the `eager_global_ordinals` to the children. Should I add `loading:eager` on the parent (`item`)? Or leave it without it?

Comment: You don't need that for this specific query. Imo you can remove them.

Comment: Argh, it didn't worked. Unfortunately it's even more slow, :(

Comment: Hm, can you provide the updated mapping?

Comment: Sure, this is the new mapping: http://pastebin.com/BjWBbzca

Comment: It's incorrect. Try this: http://pastebin.com/0qks1tBF.

Comment: Did you try with the mapping I provided in the pastebin link?

Comment: It's reindexing, give me 2h, thanks @AndreiStefan ;)

Comment: Well? Any improvement? :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm, Andrei. Thanks a lot. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? Cheers! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fielddata is used for sorting and aggregating on those specific fields. It won't help with your specific query because you don't use those fields for sorting or inside aggregations. I'd try a different type of eager loading and on the child not the fields of the parent: `"loading": "eager_global_ordinals"`. More complete example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-performance.html#_global_ordinals_and_latency).

Parent-child relationship uses global ordinals to speed up joins. Global ordinals have two purposes: lower the memory usage footprint by [associating numerics with string fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html#eager-fielddata) and the one I mentioned above.

Elasticserch is using in-memory joins between parents and children to make the relationship work. For these joins the global ordinals are used. They need to be built and pre-loaded. Using `"loading": "eager_global_ordinals"` it should preload the global ordinals and make the searches faster since these joins are already pre-loaded in memory.